# JavaFX ImageView image not showing

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I have an `assets` folder full of images to implement in a game I'm creating and I want to display these in the window. This is my code so far.

```
public class javafxtest extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

        Image test = new Image("file:assets/BA.png");
        ImageView piece = new ImageView(test);
        piece.setX(10);
        piece.setY(10);

        Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(50, 150, 500, 300);
        rct.setFill(Color.GRAY);

        root.getChildren().addAll(rct, piece);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This will be for a program to run within IntelliJ/from a jar. The assets folder is in the same directory as this file. I get no file path error so I assume it can find the image, but it doesn't appear on screen and the rectangle does.

Fair warning, I'm learning JavaFX from scratch and I'm finding there's not much explanation as to how things work, so this could be a stupid question.

Comment: If the image is added to the jar you should access it via `getResource`: `new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/BA.png").toExternalForm())`

Comment: just needs to be in intellij right now, so the above results in a null pointer exception for me

Comment: You need add your image on your project and use `getRessource()`, or you need to write full path of your image.

Comment: Try `getException().printStackTrace()` on the image view. You'll get more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing the image via the filesystem is the wrong choice when the image is in fact an asset (ie it is distributed along side the .class files that make up your program) because that way you'd have to deal with the installation path (otherwise known as the *home path*). The correct choice is bundling your image in your JAR, so place your image in the following path:

```
src/main/resources/assets/BA.png
```

and access it with:

```
Image test = new Image("/assets/BA.png");
```

This is how the file tree should look like in your computer:

[image]